# MySQL increment values of 1

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to update some values in my database, they are currently empty and I want to add them in increments of 1 starting with 1.

Example

```
Value
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar 
SET value = '1' + 1 
WHERE attribute_id = 136
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I'm using a MySQL server with phpmyadmin

Comment: Your `UPDATE` will update all records with the same value.  You'll need to use a cursor or partitioned function like `ROW_NUMBER()` to  update different rows.

Comment: Add the database tag you are using mysql,sql server or other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked in the end.

```
SET @i := 1;
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar
SET value = @i:=@i+1
WHERE attribute_id = 136;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (SQL Server only):

```
with [incremented] as
(
    select attribute_id, row_number() over(order by attribute_id) [no], value
    from catalog_product_entity_varchar
)
UPDATE [incremented]
SET value = [no];
```

[Check SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91f96/1)

Comment: You should mention that you're assuming SQL Server, since OP does not specify which DBMS this is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL server, you could do this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ebbba/4

```
declare @counter int
set @counter = 0

UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar 
SET value = @counter,
    @counter = @counter + 1
WHERE attribute_id = 136
```

Comment: I did not know that it is possible to increment the variable this way... wow! (+1)

Comment: Hmm i use SQL but when i run this its telling me to check syntax near 'declare @counter int'. I use MySQL with phpmyadmin if thats of any relevance.

Comment: My answer was assuming sql server, not mysql.  I have put in for an update to your question with the appropriate tag.  RDBMS is important in the future ;)

Comment: Ok thanks i didnt realise SQL and MySQL were different. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Answer posted. Once i realised MySQL and SQL were two different things it was just a case of doing a bit of searching for the MySQL version of this. Thanks again Kritner.